# Find max with negative numbers

Tags: python, max

I am working on this code to find the maximum of numbers entered by a user.  As it is, if I enter all negative numbers, the program returns `0` as the greatest.

What do I need to add to handle negative numbers? For instance, if a user enters `-3` and `-1`, the program should print `-1`.

```
m = 0
finished = False
while not finished:
    print('Enter a number (0 to finish): ', end = '')
    s = input()
    num = int(s)
    if num != 0:
        if num > m:
            m = num
    else:
        finished = True
print(str(m))
```

Comment: Well, what do you think needs to be done to make sure you're only looking at negative numbers? Show us what you've tried—we're not a code-writing service.

Comment: Maybe start your indicator at the lowest possible value rather than zero.

Answer (score 3):

I see three general possibilities:

1. Set **m** to a ridiculously small integer to start; I think that your current code will work from there.
2. Read the first input number *before* the loop; make that the starting value of **m**.
3. Don't use a value of m at all: append all of the input numbers to a list, and simply take the **max** of the list after the user enters **0** to stop.

Also, *please* learn to use descriptive variable names.  **finished** is good, but **m** is semantically useless, and **num** is questionable (although it *is* rather non-descript).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following approach using built-in [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function:

```
positives = []   # list for positive numbers
negatives = []   # list for negative numbers
finished = False

while not finished:
    print('Enter a number (0 to finish): ', end = '')
    num = int(input())
    if num > 0:
        positives.append(num)
    elif num < 0:
        negatives.append(num)
    else:
        finished = True

print('Max positive number: ', max(positives))
print('Max negative number: ', max(negatives))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should try to assign the maxelement initially to list[0] i.e first element of the list and then start comparing with every element of the list. This should work-

```
def calculate_max(list1) :
maxelement = list1[0]
for element in list1 :
    if element>maxelement :
        maxelement= element  
     return maxelement

#main
l=[-2,-5,-6]
result = calculate_max(l)
print(result)
```